# Counting sequences in string

Tags: perl, hash, counting

I'm working on a program which looks at a line of DNA and counts how many matches if it finds of a word of X length.

Say you read a line like this

```
AGGAACAAAAGGG
```

And with a word length being 2, it should store the values in a hash like this

```
my $word_length = 2;
my %count;

##Counting code##

%count = (
    AG => 2,
    GG => 2,
    GA => 1,
    AC => 1,
    CA => 1,
    AA => 4,
);
```

(This was counting manually, so it might be wrong).
This "counting code", that I don't have, accounts for overlaps. Which is what I'm struggling with. I have a placeholder code at the moment, but that can't detect overlaps. 
Basically,

"AAAA", should return 3 AA's, not 2.

Comment: You'll have to show an attempt. Stackoverflow will help you with coding problems, it will not write code for you. Add your placeholder code and you'll get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for my $i (0..length($s)-$word_length) {
   my $word = substr($s, $i, $word_length);
   ++$counts{$word};
}
```

(The hash contains multiple counts, so I renamed it to `%counts`.)

Comment: Thanks, ikegami! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is most concise using a global regex match.

The following code finds all positions in the string `$s` that are followed by two "word" characters (alphanumeric or underscore, which should be sufficient if your data is well-behaved) captures those characters in `$1` and increments the corresponding field of the `%counts` hash. The number of characters to be captured is represented by `$n` which is interpolated into the regex pattern

Note that there are three occurrences of `GG`, not two, because the subsequence `GGG` contains two occurrences

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dumper;

my $s = 'AGGAACAAAAGGG';

my $n = 2;

my %counts;
++$counts{$1} while $s =~ /(?=(\w{$n}))/g;

print Dumper \%counts;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'GA' => 1,
          'AA' => 4,
          'CA' => 1,
          'AC' => 1,
          'GG' => 3,
          'AG' => 2
        };
```